# Foundation Framework Sticky Topbar is not sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, vendor

I use the Foundation framework and I want the "top-bar" component to be sticky when the browser window touches the Navigation. The documentation shows an example called ["Stick Top Bar"](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html).

Now I have build that Topbar exactly like the documentation shows, but it doesn´t work...

Here's the [link](http://bit.ly/1LA4qYh) to the page.

Anyone is able to see where I fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your top-bar to be on the top and stick there, you need a `position: fixed;` . Then your top, left, right and bottom attributes will work and you will be able to put your navbar to the top by adding `top:0;`

```
 .sticky {
       top: 0;
       position: fixed;
    }
```

Add this javascript (assuming you have JQuery included)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $head = $('.navigation');
    if ($this.scrollTop() > 1000) {
       $head.addClass('sticky');
    } else {
       $head.removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

You can adjust the position at which the bar pops up with `$this.scrollTop() > yourvaluehere`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/etyb63my/3/)

Comment: Yeah but the topbar just want to be top fixed when the browser windows cross the nav element

Comment: oh, okay. This will need some javascript. I'll update my solution

Comment: Done, I added the javascript.

Comment: Ok i opened a fiddle. I think its just sticky on top. Now Scrolling...     https://jsfiddle.net/Nighteyes/etyb63my/1/

Comment: I fixed it and added a fiddle.

Comment: Hello Hristo, thank you for your request. Now i think its look good but when i reload my page i see the Navigation on Top. When i scroll this navigation hide... look: http://bit.ly/1LA4qYh

Comment: Remove the  .stickly class fro the HTML document

Comment: and add a z-index: 999 to the header so that it won't go behind anything

Comment: Funktioniert es? :))

Comment: Hallo Hristo, hatte es gestern getestet und hat alles geklappt ;) Danke dafür!